# Implementation of the max() function in Python

Tags: python

Consider:

```
def my_max(*a):
    n = len(a)
    max_v = a[0]
    for i in range (1,n):
        if a[i] > max_v:
        max_v = a[i]
    return max_v


def my_min(*a):
    n = len(a)
    min_v = a[0]
    for i in range (1,n):
        if a[i] < min_v:
            min_v = a[i]
    return min_v


test = [7, 4, 2, 6, 8]
assert max(test) == my_max(test) and min(test) == my_min(test)
assert max(7, 4, 2, 5) == my_max(7, 4, 2, 5) and min(7, 4, 2, 5)
== my_min(7, 4, 2, 5)
print("pass")
```

I am trying to write the max() function of Python in code.
If I add the asterisk in front of the input, it won't pass the first assertion.
If I don't it wouldn't pass the second assertion.

What should I write in the input for it to pass both assertions, like it does in the max() function of Python?

Comment: Your homework question got answered by one of the OG developers of the Python language itself! Kudos!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Short answer:**  Use a star to collect the arguments in a tuple and then add a special case for a tuple of length one to handle a single iterable argument.

**Source material:** The C code that handles the logic can be found at:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da20d7401de97b425897d3069f71f77b039eb16f/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1708

**Simplified pure python code**:  If you ignore the *default* and *key* keyword arguments, what's left simplifies to:

```
def mymax(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        raise TypeError('max expected at least 1 argument, got 0')
    if len(args) == 1:
        args = tuple(args[0])
    largest = args[0]
    for x in args[1:]:
        if x > largest:
            largest = x
    return largest
```

There are other nuances, but this should get you started.

**Documentation:** The special handling for the length one case versus other cases is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> Return the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more
> arguments.
>
> If one positional argument is provided, it should be an iterable. The
> largest item in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional
> arguments are provided, the largest of the positional arguments is
> returned.

**More complete version:**  This includes some of aforementioned nuances like the *key* and *default* keyword arguments and the use of iterators instead of slices:

```
sentinel = object()

def mymax(*args, default=sentinel, key=None):
    """max(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
    max(arg1, arg2, *args, *[, key=func]) -> value
    
    With a single iterable argument, return its biggest item. The
    default keyword-only argument specifies an object to return if
    the provided iterable is empty.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
    """
    if not args:
        raise TypeError('max expected at least 1 argument, got 0') 
    if len(args) == 1:
        it = iter(args[0])
    else:
        if default is not sentinel:
            raise TypeError('Cannot specify a default for max() with multiple positional arguments')
        it = iter(args)
    largest = next(it, sentinel)
    if largest is sentinel:
        if default is not sentinel:
            return default
        raise ValueError('max() arg is an empty sequence')
    if key is None:
        for x in it:
            if x > largest:
                largest = x
        return largest
    largest_key = key(largest)
    for x in it:
        kx = key(x)
        if kx > largest_key:
            largest = x
            largest_key = kx
    return largest

# This makes the tooltips nicer
# but isn't how the C code actually works
# and it is only half correct.
mymax.__text_signature__ = '($iterable, /, *, default=obj, key=func)'
```